# The argument type 'RemoteMessage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String?, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am quite new to flutter. Can anybody suggest a solution for the error "The argument type 'RemoteMessage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String?, dynamic>'" that I am gettin in my code. Line:20 & line 25 / pushNotificationService.dart.
Thank you

My code is given below:

main.dart

```
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/carInfoScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/configMaps.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/mainScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/registrationScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/DataHandler/appData.dart';

import 'AllScreens/loginScreen.dart';

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async
{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
DatabaseReference driversRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");
DatabaseReference newRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests");
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers").child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid).child("newRide");

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AppData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Driver',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? LoginScreen.idScreen : MainScreen.idScreen,
        routes: {
          RegistrationScreen.idScreen: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
          LoginScreen.idScreen: (context) => LoginScreen(),
          MainScreen.idScreen: (context) => MainScreen(),
          CarInfoS`enter code here`creen.idScreen: (context) => CarInfoScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pushNotification.dart

```
    import 'package:driver/Models/rideDetails.dart';
    import 'package:driver/configMaps.dart';
    import 'package:driver/main.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    import 'dart:io' show Platform;
    
    class PushNotificationService {
    
      final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    
      Future initialize(context) async {
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    
          RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    
          retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message));
        });
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    
          retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message));
        });
      }
    
      Future<String?> getToken() async {
        String? token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
        driversRef.child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid).child("token").set(token);
    
        firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("alldrivers");
        firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("allusers");
      }
    
      String getRideRequestId(Map<String?, dynamic> message) {
    
        String rideRequestId = "";
    
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          rideRequestId = message['data']['ride_request_id'];
        } else {
          rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
        }
        return rideRequestId;
      }
    
      void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId) {
        newRequestRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
            double pickupLocationLat =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
            double pickupLocationLng =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString());
            String pickupAddress = dataSnapshot.value['pickup_address'].toString();
    
            double dropoffLocationLat =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['dropoff']['latitude'].toString());
            double dropoffLocationLng =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['dropoff']['longitude'].toString());
            String dropoffAddress =
                dataSnapshot.value['dropoff_address'].toString();
    
            String paymentMethod = dataSnapshot.value['payment_method'].toString();
    
            String rider_name = dataSnapshot.value["rider_name"].toString();
            String rider_phone = dataSnapshot.value["rider_phone"].toString();
    
            RideDetails rideDetails = RideDetails();
            rideDetails.ride_request_id = rideRequestId;
            rideDetails.pickup_address = pickupAddress;
            rideDetails.dropoff_address = dropoffAddress;
            rideDetails.pickup = LatLng(pickupLocationLat, pickupLocationLng);
            rideDetails.dropoff = LatLng(dropoffLocationLat, dropoffLocationLng);
            rideDetails.payment_method = paymentMethod;
            rideDetails.rider_name = rider_name;
            rideDetails.rider_phone = rider_phone;
    
            print("Information :: ");
            print(rideDetails.pickup_address);
            print(rideDetails.dropoff_address);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    
    rideDetails.dart
    
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    
    class RideDetails {
      String? pickup_address;
      String? dropoff_address;
      LatLng? pickup;
      LatLng? dropoff;
      String? ride_request_id;
      String? payment_method;
      String? rider_name;
      String? rider_phone;
    
      RideDetails({this.pickup_address,this.dropoff_address, this.pickup, this.dropoff, this.ride_request_id, this.payment_method, this.rider_name, this.rider_phone});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From,

```
String getRideRequestId(Map<String?, dynamic> message) {}
```

To,

```
String getRideRequestId(var message) {}
```

For print request in console,
Try This,

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  rideRequestId = message.data['ride_request_id'];
} else {
  rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
}
print("Print Notification Data:" + rideRequestId);
return rideRequestId;
}
```

Comment: The message is sent to the phone but it shows another error as:New Ride Request
E/flutter (32202): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'RemoteMessage' has no instance method '[]'.
E/flutter (32202): Receiver: Instance of 'RemoteMessage'
E/flutter (32202): Tried calling: []("data").

Comment: In which device android or iOS?

Comment: Though the messages is received by the phone, the requested information is not printed to the console. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I am using an android device

Comment: The rideRequestId is being printed here:
I/flutter (32202): {status: done, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, id: 1, ride_request_id: -MjY-d-rZl7a6iYBeCNR}
I/flutter (32202): New Ride Request
I am looking to print the information contained in the request, such as pickup and dropoff locations which are contained in the Realtime database.

Comment: Is it because we have put the var in plae of Map?

Comment: I think the location details are provided by the(Map<String, dynamic> message) which we changed into var message. The earlier error is gone and the code runs but the ride details are missing. Is there some other way to do it without removing the (Map<String, dynamic> map)?